# How to get min and max of process memory?(c++)

Tags: c++, windows, readprocessmemory

I am trying to get all of a processes memory of a certain int. Example- I type in 33 and all the memory that contains the int 33 in the certain process is displayed. I tried searching through 0 - 9223372036854775807 (then converting back to hex) just like cheat engine's min and max search. That takes way too long. I heard every process has a different min and max. If so how do I find the min and max of a processes memory?

Comment: You probably want to look at the virtual memory mapping functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [VirtualQueryEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366907(v=vs.85).aspx) to discover ranges of memory that are in use by another process.  It's typically not as simple as one range with a min/max.  A process may have several non-contiguous ranges in memory at once.

Comment: Thank you so much!